# OpenLayers: How to create a feature icon from a memory bitmap?

Tags: canvas, bitmap, icons, openlayers

I am using OL 7 version. I am using markers on the map with a PNG icon read from file, and this works very well.

But I would like to personalize icons on the fly, ie. read some PNGs in memory (using [pngjs](https://github.com/lukeapage/pngjs) for example), combine them, adjust some pixels (stroke/fill color, background colors...) and use the resulting memory buffer as the feature icon. There are no user interactions, and a limited number (less than 1000) features, and less than 100 different icons.

I found plenty examples using PNG files, but none using memory buffers and icons made on the fly.

It looks like I have to use an HTML canvas.

This example [Openlayers 4 use canvas pattern for feature style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44982783/openlayers-4-use-canvas-pattern-for-feature-style) use a rectangle with a fill color made from a pattern created from a canvas. In that case, I would create an icon from a blank PNG file and fill it with that gradient. I think that it would work, but it is not very elegant.

When looking at the OL code, in ol/style/Icon.js, IconImage.js and Image.js, it seems possible to get the Icon's canvas and its context, and then draw onto it.

On [ImageCanvas.js](https://%20https://gist.github.com/mzur/d0ca83858c0f4e3bae807e1857801621), Mzur is also doing something similar, but with an ImageStatic source.

On   [The Book of OpenLayers3](https://www.acuriousanimal.com/thebookofopenlayers3/chapter03_04_imagecanvas.html), A. Santiago is also doing something similar, but with an Image layer.

I do not have too much experience with OL, and I am really confused about the differences between Image, ImageStatic and Icon.

So What should I do?

Thanks,

Michel

Comment: An icon style can use either an image or a canvas element as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/icon-negative.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Mike, for showing me this. I have created a working example on github, and will answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Mike for putting me on the right direction.

It turned out to be complicated because:

- It is difficult to import binary data. I used
  @H.B.'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73847316/import-raw-image-data-into-a-script-with-vite)
- There are not so many maintained PNG parsing libraries without too many dependencies, working in the browser and decoding an existing bitmap. I used the excellent [UPNG.js](https://github.com/photopea/UPNG.js) library.
- Then mastering OpenLayers...

I have created a simple working example available [here](https://github.com/mgurzixo/ol-bitmap)